# Strong glitch with Evaluate in Manipulate

Tags: graphics, differential-equations, performance-tuning, manipulate, evaluation

I'm experiencing a strong evaluation problem for a `Manipulate` box and I can't find the best solution yet.  Here's a MWE to show the glitch :

```
sol[a_] := NDSolve[{
    x''[t] == -2 x[t],
    x[0] == a,
    x'[0] == 1
    }, {x}, {t, 0, 10}]

position[t_, a_] := Evaluate[{Sin[x[t]], Cos[x[t]]}/.sol[a]][[1]]

test[t_, a_] := Graphics[{Darker[Blue], Disk[position[t, a], 0.05]}];

trajectory[t_, a_] := ParametricPlot[
    (* Evaluate[{Sin[x[s]], Cos[x[s]]}/.sol[a]] *)
    position[s, a],
    {s, Max[0.001, t - 2], t},
    ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Opacity[0.5, White], RGBColor[0.40, 0.40, 0.80]}, #3] &)
]

Manipulate[
    Show[{test[t, a], trajectory[t, a]}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}],
    {{t, 0, "t"}, 0, 10, 0.01},
    {{a, 1, "a"}, -1, 1, 0.01}
]
```

This code apparently works (it's a bit laggy, though), but it doesn't work at all for my complete project because of a strong performance issue.

The source of the problem appears to be the `[[1]]` at the end of the `position[t, a]` function.  Yet, I need that `[[1]]`for the `test[t, a]`function to work properly.  However, the `trajectory[t, a]` function is working ***much*** better without the `[[1]]` in the definition of `position[t, a]`.

So what should be the best way to define `position[t, a]`, without that pesky `[[1]]`, so I could use that function in both `test[t, a]` and `trajectory[t, a]`?

I don't want to make a double definition of `position[]`, so the whole code remains simple.

Comment: What happens if you use `position[t_, a_] = Evaluate[{Sin[x[t]], Cos[x[t]]} /. sol[a]][[1]]`? -- that is, replace `:=` with `=`.

Comment: @m_goldberg, it simply doesn't work.  I'm getting several error messages.  This function needs its `:=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would memoize `sol[a]`.  The `Evaluate` in `position` does nothing if it does not wrap the ***entire*** expression after the `:=`.  It's not that important, so I would just drop it.  The issue with `[[1]]` (or `First`) can be handle in `sol`.  Here are the changes I've described:

```
sol[a_] :=
 sol[a] = First@NDSolve[{x''[t] == -2 x[t], x[0] == a, x'[0] == 1}, {x}, {t, 0, 10}]

position[t_, a_] := {Sin[x[t]], Cos[x[t]]} /. sol[a];
```

Keeping the other functions the same, the `Manipulate` runs quickly.

Comment: Why do you prefer to add memorization of the `sol[a]` function ?  Is it accelerating a bit the whole Manipulate code ?

Comment: @Cham Yes it saves the result of `NDSolve` for each `a` that is used.  This is the big time savings -- nothing else really matters as far as speed goes.  Since you discretized the steps for `a` in the `Manipulate`, it won't save very many computations, and it won't use up a lot of memory.  This is what `ParametricNDSolve` does automatically.  (Actually, it saves only the one computed for the most recent `a`, I think, but that is enough to speed up the moving of the `t` slider in V9+.)

Comment: Thanks.  Your solution works great.

Answer (score 4):

Without diving into your code too much, everything will run a LOT more smoothly if you use `ParametricNDSolve` to solve your differential equations with the parameter `a`:

```
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x''[t] == -2 x[t], x[0] == a, x'[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 10}, {a}]

position[t_, a_] := {Sin[#], Cos[#]} &@pfun[a][t]
```

You can keep everything else the same. Runs much more quickly. Also, cool blue tail!!

Comment: Sadly, `ParametricNDSolve ` is unknown to my old MMA version 7.

Comment: @Cham While I think every question should have the best answer for the current version regardless of the OP's version (for the sake of all site visitors), people looking for solutions that work in earlier versions ought to include that in their question statement.  You seem not to do that.  Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

This helps to get rid of that `[[1]]` as per your request, however without having the code that is really slowing this down, I cannot be sure it would help improve your performance. If it does, great! If not, you have eliminated one possible cause.

You state the performance glitch is with `position[t,a]` function. However, can you remove the `0.01` timesteps in the `Manipulate` and leave the iteration accuracy to the optimization algorithms of `Manipulate`?

Anyway,  use `Flatten@NDSOLVE[ ... ]` and then correct for everywhere you use `sol[a][[1]]` and remove the `[[1]]`.

This should work:

```
sol[a_] := 
    Flatten@NDSolve[{x''[t] == -2 x[t], x[0] == a, x'[0] == 1}, {x}, {t, 
    0, 10}]

position[t_, a_] := {Sin[x[t]], Cos[x[t]]} /. sol[a] (*no need for Evaluate*)

test[t_, a_] := Graphics[{Darker[Blue], Disk[position[t, a], 0.05]}]

trajectory[t_, a_] := 
    ParametricPlot[position[s, a], {s, Max[0.001, t - 2], t}, 
      ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Opacity[0.5, White],RGBColor[0.40, 0.40, 0.80]}, #3] &)]

Manipulate[
 Show[{test[t, a], trajectory[t, a]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}], {{t, 0, "t"}, 0, 10}, {{a, 1, "a"}, -1, 1}
]
```